# WooCommerce REST API with Android e-commerce app

Tags: java, android, post, woocommerce, get

I was trying for several hours to figure out how the WooCommerce API works by searching on Google and their official site. I found out that they officially support Node.js, Ruby, Python and PHP. But, it doesn't seem like there is an official library for Android.

However, after searching, I was very happy when I found out that there was a [Java library](https://github.com/icoderman/wc-api-java) that could help. I compiled it with IntelliJ IDEA but it throws an error:

`Return code 1 for dex process`

then another one:

`Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference`

and then the app crashes. It's strange because it's a Java library and I've read online that IntelliJ IDEA can compile java libraries and make them usable.

I searched back on Google and found unofficial Android libraries that were made 2 years ago and the API was very old back then. I searched on StackOverflow and on many other websites with no luck.

I'd like to make `GET` requests to *get the posts*, *get the orders* and so on and `POST` requests to *update user info*, *make orders* and so on. So if anyone has a **piece of code**, an **Android library**, **a way** to make this library work or even **already made it work** with his own app, please do share it with me!

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to build a sample Android application with a wc-api-java library after setting Java version to 1.8 in compile options of Gradle config:

```
defaultConfig {
        ...
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
}
```

Comment: I didn't work for me, I saw the issue on the repo, @icoderman looks like the library need to be written with JDK7 in order to make it work compatible with android easily.